# Blue Screen at booting Windows 2000 virtual

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, windows-2000

I've an Oracle VirtualBox running on a PC

The PC:

- Windows 7 SP1 64bit
- Intel G630 @ 2.7Ghz
- 2GB RAM

I used a VHD image which contains a Windows 2000 system with some pre-configured stuff and software for a customer.

At Windows boot, immediately after the "Loading Windows 2000..." screen I get the following Error:
Sorry for the German Text but it says something like "Check the Size of your HDD. If the error contains a driver, deactivate it and try again. Or change the storage controller." 
[image: Error]

The HDD Size shouldn't be a problem. Can anyone give me an advice what i can try to do?

I just tested the same combination of the VHD image and oracle VirtualBox on another computer. Same issue.

Comment: have you tried increasing the size of the VHD?

Comment: the size of the VHD is setup to be dynamically increaseable

Comment: The VHD might be thinprovisioned, but it reports some fixed site to the OS. Also, ***Windows 2000***, really? Way past time to migrate to something newer, and I don't want to hear about how newer platforms don't support the software. Trying to keep a system that old an unsupported going is going to go an arm and three legs. It's going to cost much more than the cost to replace the system with something supportable.

Answer (score 5):

Windows does not respond well to certain types of hardware change. It is virtually guaranteed to generate blue screens **if the storage controller for the system drive (C:) changes**. It'll keep using the same old (wrong) driver indefinitely. You cannot fix this without opening up the Windows partition and doing some serious brain surgery. Windows 2000 in particular is notoriously terrible at dealing with this.

From the looks of it, you pulled down a VMware image and imported it into VirtualBox. Unfortunately, VirtualBox doesn't manipulate the disk image to allow it to work with the VirtualBox-provided virtualized storage controller.

Comment: +1, seconded.  I've had that exact problem with Windows 2000 machines and VMWare.  I ended up having to build "new" Windows 2000 VM images <shudder> for the VMs that absolutely had to be Win 2k for whatever reason.  The rest I built on a modern OS - Win2k3 R2 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, i reckon it could be the additional devices configured on the image. Try and remove all USBs, cd/dvd drives, floppy drives before booting.

The image not quite what you would see, but gives you an idea what I'm talking about!

[image: virtualhardware]

If it does boot this time around, after removing the virtual hardware, update all drivers if possible.

Comment: tryed it. doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

According to [the bugtracker](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5883), this was due to enabling hardware accelerated virtualization - but it was also supposed to be fixed in 3.2.0. Since Win2k isn't an actively tested guest OS, maybe there's been a regression; try disabling vt-d/vt-x.

Comment: disabling vt-d/vt-x doesn't help.. well i gonna try Microsoft Virtual PC. Thank you